# Find a Basis of the Image of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having trouble solving this equation. I know how to find a basis for the null space but I'm unsure how to find the basis for the image of A. Any help on how I approach this problem?

[image]

Comment: When you multiply a matrix with a vector, you basically gets a linear combinations of the columns of the matrix. Therefore, the image of a linear transformation such as that is the column space of the matrix $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Find a basis for the space spanned by the columns of $A$ (Every vector in the image of $A$ is a linear combination of the columns).